# Invalid Syntax at break

Tags: python

```
a = 0
dots = []
while True:
    a = c.find('.', a+1)
    print(a)
    dots.append(a) if (a != -1) else break
```

Why does this return an invalid syntax at the break?

Comment: Because an expression is expected but `break` is a statement

Comment: @Ashwin take the time to indent code well, this is a basic syntax issue, I think it is better to you to read an introduction to python form A-Z

Comment: Thanks! As it is evident I am starting out, do need to read more.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the [conditional operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator) that way.

You *could* write something like:

```
is_even = True if x%2==0 else False
# or
result = foo() if should_call_foo else None
```

when you're deciding which of two options to assign to a variable.

But `break` is a control statement and can't go here.

You probably want something using the traditional if/else approach, for example:

```
a = 0
dots = []
while True:
    a = c.find('.', a+1)
    print(a)
    if (a != -1):
        dots.append(a)
    else:
        break
```

Comment: `is_even = x % 2 == 0`

Comment: @chepner Absolutely.  I actually added that second example in because the first one was silly (it also, sort of, demonstrates lazy evaluation capabilities of the ternary expression).

Comment: This helps a lot. Didn't know that it mandated the need for an expression and not any statement.